# Unable to show PDF file on the webpage

Tags: reactjs, pdf, react-pdfrenderer

I tried to use `@react-pdf/renderer` NPM library to embed my resume on my portfolio site. However, my resume wasn't shown correctly, as shown below:

[image: screenshot]

It shows only a blank page. I have checked my code again and again but couldn't spot any error.

Click [here](https://github.com/magickw/ReactPortfolio-BG) for the source code and [here](https://guobao.vercel.app/) for live demo.

I have tried to simplify the code as much as possible, but the has issue persisted.

Comment: You could just link to a static PDF file, since Chrome and Edge at least include built-in PDF file viewers.

Comment: Thank you. It's an option. However, I really wanted to figure out what caused that issue and how to fix it.